Existence of 2-fold branched covers
According to pages 57 and 58 of this paper by Gordon and Litherland:
"Suppose $F$ is a (possibly non-orientable) surface properly embedded in $D^4$. Then, by a standard duality argument, $H_1(D^4-F ; \mathbb{Z}_2) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$, generated by a meridian of $F$. Hence we can form the 2-fold branched cover of $D^4$ with branch set $F$; we will denote this by $M_F$."
What theorem is upholding the last sentence? Let $X$ be the disk bundle of $T(S^2)$ (so that $\partial X = \mathbb{R}P^3$), and $F \subseteq X$ a (possibly non-orientable) compact surface without closed components and with $\partial F \subseteq \partial X$ and $\text{int}(F) \subseteq \text{int}(X)$. Can we form the 2-fold branched cover of $X$ with branch set $F$?

I wrote an answer but realized I had a gap. If one knew that the natural homomorphism $H_1(D^4-F;\mathbb Z) \mapsto H_1(D^4-F;\mathbb Z_2) \approx \mathbb Z_2$ was surjective, this would be straightforward, by combining the Hurewicz theorem with covering space theory... but I'm not sure why it is surjective.

Doesn't that map just send even multiples of the meridian to 0 and odd multiples to 1? Then certainly it is surjective. How does the proof proceed?

@LeeMosher Isn't this true for any space? The sequence $0 \to \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{\cdot 2} \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} / 2 \to 0$ induces a Bockstein exact sequence $\cdots \to H_2(X; \mathbb{Z} / 2) \to H_1(X; \mathbb{Z}) \xrightarrow{\cdot 2} H_1(X; \mathbb{Z}) \xrightarrow{\text{mod } 2} H_1(X; \mathbb{Z} / 2) \to H_0(X; \mathbb{Z}) \to \cdots$, but $H_0(X; \mathbb{Z})$ is free, so $H_1(X; \mathbb{Z} / 2) \to H_0(X; \mathbb{Z})$ is 0 and the reduction map is surjective.

Ah, that's what I was missing, I was thinking of "just" the universal coefficients theorem.

There are a few standard results being applied here.
First is the Hurewicz theorem which gives a surjective homomorphism $\pi_1(D^4-F) \mapsto H_1(D^4-F;\mathbb Z)$ (whose kernel is the commutator subgroup of $\pi_1(D^4-F)$).
Next is a natural surjective homomorphism $H_1(D^4-F;\mathbb Z) \mapsto H_1(D^4-F;\mathbb Z_2)$, coming from the Bockstein short exact sequence associated to the homomorphism $\mathbb Z \mapsto \mathbb Z_2$, as in the comment of Ben Steffan.
Putting these together, we obtain a surjective homomorphism
$$\phi : \pi_1(D^4-F) \mapsto \mathbb Z_2
$$
The last step is covering space theory: the kernel of $\phi$ is an index $2$ normal subgroup; covering space theory then gives us a degree $2$, normal covering map $\tilde X \mapsto D^4-F$ with connected cover $\tilde X$, on which $\mathbb Z_2$ acts as the group of deck transformations.
There is a little cleaning up to do, proving that one can compactify $\tilde X$ by "filling $F$ in", to get a branched covering map which is one-to-one over $F$, restricting to a homeomorphism on the filled-in copy of $F$.
